# Laravel no crea el archivo webpack.mix.js

Tags: laravel, webpack, laragon

Soy nuevo usando Laravel, estoy trabajando con laragon y he creado un proyecto, me he fijado que no se ha creado el archivo webpack.mix.js y lo necesito para configurar tailwind estoy usando la version 8.1.5 de php

[image: Con php 8.1.5]

me he fijado que cuando creo proyectos con la version de php 7.4.19 si crea ese archivo webpack.mix.js y no entiendo el por que.

[image: Con php 7.4]

Comment: Versión de Laravel?

Comment: Desde hace unos días, los nuevos proyectos de Laravel usan Vite para agrupar activos frontend https://mobile.twitter.com/taylorotwell/status/1541795873838989314

Comment: mi version de laravel es 9.19.0. No sabia eso de vite. gracias voy a documentarme un poco, estaba intentando instalar tailwind

Comment: Creo que viene con tailwind por default https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/frontend#inertia-starter-kits. Depende de cómo lo instalaste